# iPad - UISplitViewController - Background color

Tags: ipad, uisplitviewcontroller, background-color

I have a UISplitViewController setup, but for some reason the background isn't taking hold until you've rotated it once.

I use IB to setup the split view and set the detail view to be `IPadDetailViewController`. Inside that I have the following:

```
- (void)loadView {
    [super loadView];

    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];

    toolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
    toolbar.barStyle = UIBarStyleDefault;
    [toolbar sizeToFit];
    [self.view addSubview:toolbar];

}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor orangeColor];
}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    if (self.interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft ||
        self.interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight) {
        NSLog(@"it is in landscape!");
        self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor]];       
    }
    else {
        NSLog(@"it is in portrait!");
        self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];

    }   
}
```

Though the code gets run and my toolbar gets place at the top, the view remains black (it starts in landscape for the Simulator).

Any ideas why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try setting the background color in awakeFromNib method in your iPadDetailViewController

Comment: The other way i could think of probably is in the SplitViewAppDelegate, setting the color of the view before it is pushed by checking the current orientation. I experienced this problem that the first orientation that comes in is 0 (unknown). If you are using a variable for orientation in your detailController you could set that variable up before it is pushed and use that variable to do orientation checking in the detailController. Hope it helps.

Comment: The issue was that I was also trying to set an image for the background and I had the wrong file name. Thanks for the help.